# ActiveRecord Exception: Could not find configuration

Tags: c#, nhibernate, activerecord, configuration

I am trying Castle.ActiveRecord for the first time.  I have the following class defined in my model:

```
[ActiveRecord("ClientObjects")]
public class ClientObject : ActiveRecordBase<ClientObject>
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }

    [BelongsTo("ClientId", NotNull = true, UniqueKey = "uxClientObjects.Client.Name")]
    public virtual Client Client { get; set; }

    [Property(NotNull = true, Length = 250)]
    public virtual string Type { get; set; }

    [Property(NotNull = true, Length = 70, UniqueKey = "uxClientObjects.Client.Name")]
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

    [HasMany(typeof(ClientGroupAccess), ColumnKey = "ClientObjectId", Table = "ClientGroupAccess")]
    public virtual IList<ClientGroupAccess> ObjectAccess { get; set; }
}
```

...when I try to generate the sql I get an exception like so:

```
ActiveRecordException: Could not find configuration for (my namespace).Entities.ClientObject or its root type Castle.ActiveRecord.ActiveRecordBase this is usually an indication that the configuration has not been setup correctly.
```

Can someone suggest what might be wrong with my configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the `Inverse` property needed to be set:

```
[ActiveRecord("ClientObjects")]
public class ClientObject : ActiveRecordBase<ClientObject>
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }

    [BelongsTo("ClientId", NotNull = true, UniqueKey = "uxClientObjects.Client.Name")]
    public virtual Client Client { get; set; }

    [Property(NotNull = true, Length = 250)]
    public virtual string Type { get; set; }

    [Property(NotNull = true, Length = 70, UniqueKey = "uxClientObjects.Client.Name")]
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

    [HasMany(typeof(ClientGroupAccess), Inverse = true)]
    public virtual IList<ClientGroupAccess> ObjectAccess { get; set; }
}
```